# Android Studio: Flutter tooltip for Widget arguments

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm trying out Android Studio for Flutter development.

A feature I lack from Visual Studio Code is the tooltip that displays when tapping `opt + esc` (on Mac) and lets me choose the argument for the widget.

[image]

Is there a similar thing in Android Studio ?

Answer (score 1):

When you hover on the widgets it will show all the available parameters. If you hold command and click on the widget it will open its class and you can see all the vales there too..

Comment: Yes indeed but I feel like it's really time waisting and clunky to click on each widget whereas a simple pop-up takes few seconds to read and use.

Comment: if you hover on the widget it will show all values in it

Comment: It's still better than nothing, sure! But what I'm looking for doesn't any use of mouse... :/
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try `Cntl + Space`(on Windows, maybe similar in Mac). I'm sure this is what you want.